# Nginx limit requests globally

Tags: nginx

I have searched the whole website and google and couldnt find what i am looking for.

Currently i know that we can limit requests / ip with for example

> limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:30m rate=20r/s;

and we can use in any location we want like

> limit_req zone=one burst=10 nodelay;

My question is. How do i limit requests globally for all ips at the same time? In short, i have a PHP-FPM location, that i want no matter what, all requests to not exceed 200 requests / second.

I guess we have to replace the $binary_remote_addr, but i have no idea with what.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make something up, that is unique and won't match anything else.

That field in [`limit_req_zone`](https://nginx.org/r/limit_req_zone) is just a key, and it's used as a lookup in the specified `zone`. If you have a static key, then all the lookups will match the same, and the limit for that zone will be effectively global.

For example:

```
limit_req_zone global zone=my_php_location_to_limit:1k rate=200/s;
```

Here, `global` has no semantic meaning. It's just a random bit of text. It could be `anything` or `something` or `nothing`.

Comment: Ah! I'm so dumb. Now i noticed. You made also the zone 1k, because since the key is static it wont exceed 1k?

Comment: It'll only really be a few bytes. So why waste memory?