# How to limit Nginx to max 50 request per second independent from IP

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting

I'm looking for a way to limit Nginx for location to a number of requests per second *independent* of the origin IP. From my understanding the rate limiting feature is IP sensitive which cannot be turned off.

What would be the right approach here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx limit requests globally](https://serverfault.com/questions/817164/nginx-limit-requests-globally)

Comment: From my understanding all these options are by IP. So it works if you have e.g. 10r/m from one IP, but what you having request from a /8 or even /0? Am I just missunderstanding the documentation maybe?

Comment: All those options aren't by IP.  The answer here uses a static word (global) to bucket the requests, so all requests will go in the same bucket and be limited independent of IP: https://serverfault.com/a/817165/362828

This part in the question is what makes it by IP: `$binary_remote_addr`.  But that key can be set to anything (e.g. you could limit based on a cookie or the request url).

Answer (score 0):

Like so

```
limit_req_zone global zone=global_limit:1k rate=50/s;
```

The `global` part is the key Nginx uses to bucket requests.  By setting it to a static string (could be anything), rather than a variable, all requests will go into the same bucket.

To limit by IP, you would set it to `$binary_remote_addr`.  You can rate limit on just about anything (see https://www.nginx.com/blog/dynamic-bandwidth-limits-nginx-plus-key-value-store/#Complete-Sample-NGINX-Configuratio for a complex example).